# Static Referencing of Member Values - Ada

Tags: ada, static-members

Hi 
I am trying out my first program in Ada of creating a single player dice game.
But facing problem in maintaining score of the player.
Goal: Each player has 10 turns and scores 10 points if total of 2 rolls is 7
Problem: Every time total score gets reset and 10 does not get added to current score.
Total_Score is the final score to be displayed.
Please help!!! Any help appreciated!!!

Thanks :)

My code is as follows:

```
with Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random,Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

   procedure Game is

      subtype Die is Integer range 1 .. 6;
      subtype Dice is Integer range 2*Die'First .. 2*Die'Last;
      package Random_Die is new Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random (Die);
      use Random_Die;

  type MY_TYPE is range 1..10;
  package My_Int_IO is new Ada.Text_IO.Integer_IO(MY_TYPE);
  use My_Int_IO;

  My_Range : MY_TYPE;
      G : Generator;
      Roll : Dice;  -- Total Rolled
  Roll_One : INTEGER;   -- Roll 1
  Roll_Two : INTEGER;   -- Roll 2
  Total_Score : INTEGER;    -- Current Score
  Choice : INTEGER;     -- Game Choice
  Total_Roll : INTEGER;     -- Total Rolled Returned
  Score : INTEGER;  -- Static Score count

  function Roll_Dice return INTEGER is
   begin
    -- Start the generator in a unique state in each run
        Reset (G); 
    Total_Score := 0;
            -- Roll a pair of dice
        Roll_One := Random(G);
        Roll_Two := Random(G);
    Put(Roll_One,3);
        Put(Roll_Two,3);
            Roll := Roll_One + Roll_Two;
        return Roll;
  end Roll_Dice;

   begin
   Total_Score := 0;
   for Index in MY_TYPE loop
    Put("Roll Dice: Press 1 To Exit: Press 2 ");
    New_Line;
    Get(Item => Choice);
    if Choice = 1 then
       Total_Roll := Roll_Dice;
       if Total_Roll = 7 then
        Put("Current Score : ");
        Put(Total_Score , 3);
        Total_Score := Total_Score + 10;
            New_Line;
        Put("Your Score :  ");
        Put(Total_Score, 3);
            else
        New_Line;
        Put("Sorry! you do not score");
            end if;
    elsif Choice = 2 then
       Put("Score ");
       Put(Total_Score, 3);
       exit when Choice = 2;
    else
       Put("Wrong Choice! You lost one chance! Try Again");
    end if;
   end loop;
    New_Line;
    Put("Total Score for this game: ");
    Put(Total_Score, 3);
   end Game;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Every time total score gets reset and 10 does not get added to current score.

That's because you set `Total_Score` to zero in the `Roll_Dice` function:

```
Total_Score := 0;
```

10 **does** get added to `Total_Score`:

```
Total_Score := Total_Score + 10;
```

but on the subsequent roll, the total is reset to zero.

Comment: Thanks!!!! I completely missed it!!! Cant believe I spent so much time on it :( Thanks so much!